# Obtener saltos de numeración con SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla de inventario con la siguiente estructura:

tabla1
Id
Numero_de_caja
Descripcion
Activo

Y supongamos que tiene este contenido:

1 - 1 - caja1 - 1
2 - 2 - caja2 - 1
3 - 3 - caja3 - 0
4 - 4 - caja4 - 1

El campo `Activo` sirve para el borrado lógico. Es decir, si existe físicamente en el depósito, va con `Activo = 1`, si no está físicamente en el depósito va con `Activo = 0`.
Es decir que la caja número 3 (Numero_de_caja) estaría disponible físicamente. Por lo que si quiero agregar una caja nueva el contenido de la tabla debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

1 - 1 - descripcion1 - 1
2 - 2 - descripcion2 - 1
3 - 3 - descripcion3 - 0
4 - 4 - descripcion4 - 1
5 - 3 - descripcion5 - 1

Cómo hago vía `query`  para que me muestre el primer hueco (El más chico) disponible (Activo =1), es decir que para el ejemplo anterior, que me diga que el 3 está disponible.

Comment: Solo para estar seguro que entiendo: a partir del momento que le agregas el registro `5 - 3 - descripcion5 - 1`, ya la caja #3 no está disponible, de modo que la sentencia SQL no debería devolver `3`. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: ¿Y que pasa si ninguna de las cajas que se encuentran en la tabla está disponible? ¿Qué debería hacer el query en ese caso?

Comment: Lo que necesito es mostrar el numero de caja más pequeño que no esté en activo = 1

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es lo que significa si en tu tabla tienes 2 registros para la caja #3, uno con `activo = 0` y el otro con `activo = 1`.  A pesar del registro con `activo = 1`, sigues considerando que la caja #3 esta disponible? Me parece raro. Hay algo que no entiendo.  Tal vez si incluyes mas ejemplos variados en tu pregunta, esto aclararía la duda.

Comment: En teoría no deberían reactivarse, es decir no pasarían a activo = 1 una vez que están en 0. Es sólo para mantener un registro. En caso que sí o sí haya que reactivarla, es lo mismo que cuando agrego una nueva, me debería sugerir el menor número disponible Activo = 1

Comment: Básicamente es: tengo Activo = 1 las cajas 1-2-4-5 y Activo = 0 las cajas 2-3-4. Si quiero agregar una caja nueva el sistema o la consulta debe mostrar que la próxima caja disponible es la 3.

Comment: Si quisiera reactivar la caja 4 por ejemplo de los que están en Activo = 0, me debe sugerir colocarle el número 3

Comment: *tengo Activo = 1 las cajas 1-2-4-5 y Activo = 0 las cajas 2-3-4*: Porque dices que la proxima caja disponible es `3` en este caso?  No debería ser `2`?  Pregunto, porque en otro comentario que dejastes bajo una de las respuestas dijistes: *Necesito que me muestre el primer número de caja disponible, ya sea porque el estado está en Activo = 0 o porque nunca se cargó una caja con ese número*. En este caso, no sería la caja #2?

Comment: Exacto, es un ABM de cajas. Yo cuando agrego una caja totalmente nueva me debería mostrar cuál es el número de caja más pequeño disponible, es decir que no esté utlizado por una acaja con Activo = 1. En el ejemplo, como las activas son 1-2-4-5, me debería sugerir el número 3 ya que está disponible, por más que haya un Activo=0 con ese número (que estaría dado de baja lógicamente)

Comment: Ok, ahora empiezo a entender.  Y en tu ejemplo, si hubiera un registro con `activo = 1` para la caja #3, entonces deberia sugerir #6?

Comment: Si, eso mismo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esta es la sentencia que estás buscando:

```
select coalesce(
          min(t1.numero_de_caja),
          (select coalesce(max(numero_de_caja), 0) + 1
             from tabla1)
       )
  from tabla1 t1
 where t1.activo = 0
   and not exists (select null
                     from tabla1 t2
                    where t2.numero_de_caja = t1.numero_de_caja
                      and t2.activo = 1)
```

Lo que entiendo es que quieres el número de caja mas pequeño con `activo = 0` pero donde no existe ningún regístro con `activo = 1`.  Y de no encontrar ningún número de caja que respete ese criterio, entonces debería devolver el número de caja mas pequeño que nunca se haya usado antes en la tabla.

Comment: Exacto, el número más chico que no esté en Activo = 1 o que esté en Activo = 0. La consulta que me pasaste me devolvió NULL

Comment: Ok, hice el ajuste. Creo que ahora sí hace lo que estas pidiendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Estuve buscando la forma de contarctarte, pero no vi la opción de mensaje privado. Tengo otro problema relacionado con esto, quizás un poco más complejo. Si me pudieras dar otra mano te estaría muy agradecido :D http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29058/comparar-1-a-1-filas-en-sql

Comment: Creo que ya lo solucióne!

Answer (score 0):

Quiza con

```
select * from tabla1 -- traemos todos los datos del registro

where Activo = 0 -- solo traemos activos

order by Numero_de_caja -- ordenamos ascendentemente por numero de caja

limit 0,1 -- con esto solo traemos el primer registro
```

Comment: Probé eso, pero bajo ciertas circunstacias no funciona. Por ejemplo:

Comment: Si tengo activa la caja 1 y desactivada la caja 1, no debería mostrarme el número 1

Comment: Lo que necesito es ver cuál es el primer número activo disponible. Si no hay huecos uso el que le sigue al último

Comment: Ok, podrias aclarame el segundo comentario **Si tengo activa la caja 1 y desactivada la caja 1**

Comment: Sí, por supuesto.

Comment: Te lo pongo con un ejemplo así queda un poco más claro: yo tengo un lugar físico donde guardo cajas. Estas cajas tienen un número correlativo y hay un máximo de lugar para 500 cajas.

Comment: Estas cajas se dan de alta y baja con bastante frecuencia, por lo que cada vez que se da de baja una caja el número/lugar que ocupaba queda disponible para colocar nuevas cajas

Comment: Cuando doy de baja una caja, esta no se elimina de la base de datos, sólo pasa a Activo = 0, es decir mantiene su número de caja

Comment: Ese número que mantiene la caja dada de baja, debería estar disponible para utilizar una caja nueva, y en caso que sea el menor número (el mas chico) disponible, que sea ese el valor que salga de la consulta

Comment: Deberías manejar un 3er estado, 1 Activo, 0 Disponible, -1 para Desactivado, así tendría más sentido la sugerencia que te dio @jasilva

Comment: Ok podrias agregar un caso en el que no funcione, para proponer una nueva cosa

Comment: En realidad lo que nececito es más simple. Necesito que me muestre el primer número de caja disponible, ya sea porque el estado está en Activo = 0 o porque nunca se cargó una caja con ese número

Answer (score 0):

No entendí muy bien, pero ¿No sería así?

```
select * from tabla1
where Numero_de_caja = 3
and   Activo in (select min(Activo) from tabla1
                 where Numero_de_caja = 3)
```

Comment: Pero debería ser dinámico, es decir, la parte del where no va a ser siempre 3

Comment: Es que yo entendí que el lugar disponible según el número de caja, pero si no quieres usar el número de caja, entonces así:
    select * from tabla1
    where Activo in (select min(Activo) from tabla1)

Comment: Lo que quiero en realidad es mostrar cual es el primer número de caja disponible, ya sea porque está inactivo, o porque nunca fue utiizado

Comment: Ok, si solo manejas dos status, 0 para cajas que existieron y ya no están y 1 para cajas que si están, podría ser así: `select * from tabla1 where Numero_de_caja in (select min(Numero_de_caja) where Activo = 0)`, pero si son cajas que nunca existieron, y tienes las cajas 1, 2, 4 y 5, la 3, que nunca existió, no te va a salir con queries. Ahí tienes que buscar otra solución.

Comment: Justamente es eso lo que estoy buscando xD

Comment: Jejeje, excelente