# Comparar 1 a 1 filas en SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buenas, avanzando un poco más me topé con otro problema:

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
Tabla1
+----+--------------------+-------------+-------+------------+
| Id | ultima_realizacion | vencimiento | tarea | id_cliente |
+----+--------------------+-------------+-------+------------+
```

- Por cliente se cargan 5 tareas (tarea1, tarea2,...,tarea5).
- Por cada tarea se debe cargar 1 sola fecha (en ultima_realizacion o bien en vencimiento)

La elección de dónde se carga es porque hay:

- Tareas mensuales (se cargan en ultima_realizacion)
- Tareas anuales (se cargan en vencimiento)

Cuando cargo en un campo fecha el otro debe quedar sí o sí en **'0000-00-00'**
Es decir, si cargo una fecha en "*ultima_realizacion*", en el campo "*vencimiento*" va **'0000-00-00'** y lo mismo al revez, si cargo una fecha en "*vencimiento*", en el campo "*ultima_realizacion*" va **'0000-00-00'**.

Ahora bien, puede que alguna tarea mensual o anual **no aplique** para cierto cliente.
**No aplica** quiere decir que no es tenida en cuenta para ese cliente. 
En ese caso:

- Si es mensual, en el campo "*ultima_realizacion*" va **'0001-01-01'** y en "*vencimiento*" queda **'0000-00-00'**
- Si es anual, en el campo "*vencimiento*" va **'0001-01-01'** y en "*ultima_realizacion*" va **'0000-00-00'**

Cuando agrego un cliente nuevo a esta tabla, automáticamente se le pone a ambos campos de fechas la fecha **'0000-00-00'**

Es decir, queda de la siguiente manera:

```
Tabla1
+----+--------------------+-------------+-------+------------+
| Id | ultima_realizacion | vencimiento | tarea | id_cliente |
+----+--------------------+-------------+-------+------------+
 1     0000-00-00           0000-00-00     1       1
 2     0000-00-00           0000-00-00     2       1
 3     0000-00-00           0000-00-00     3       1
 4     0000-00-00           0000-00-00     4       1
 5     0000-00-00           0000-00-00     5       1
```

Si ambas fechas "*ultima_realizacion*" y "*vencimiento*" están en **'0000-00-00'**, quiere decir que el cliente **no fue seteado**.

En ese caso debería mostrar un mensaje diciendo que no fue seteado.

Ahora, si tengo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
Tabla1
+----+--------------------+-------------+-------+------------+
| Id | ultima_realizacion | vencimiento | tarea | id_cliente |
+----+--------------------+-------------+-------+------------+
 1     0001-01-01           0000-00-00   tarea1       1
 2     2016-08-10           0000-00-00   tarea2       1
 3     0000-00-00           0001-01-01   tarea3       1
 4     0000-01-01           0000-00-00   tarea4       1
 5     0000-00-00           2016-10-01   tarea5       1
```

Esto quiere decir:

- "tarea1" es mensual y no aplica
- "tarea2" es mensaul y la fecha de "ultima_realizacion" fue '2016-08-10'
- "tarea3" es anual y no aplica
- "tarea4" es mensual y no aplica
- "tarea5" es anual y la fecha de "vencimiento" fue '2016-10-01'

**Lo que necesito es que:**

- Me muestre si el cliente está o no seteado. En el ejemplo anterior, el cliente está seteado, ya que la condición "*WHERE ultima_realizacion = 000-00-00 AND vencimiento = 0000-00-00*" no se cumple.
- Que las tareas que no apliquen (que estén 0001-01-01) no me influyan en la fórmula de vencimiento que voy a describir más adelante.
- Que me avise si existe al menos 1 tarea vencida o no

**Fórmula de vencimiento.**

Si es una tarea anual, comparo la fecha de hoy con la de "vencimiento"

*if(vencimiento < hoy) echo "Tareas retrasadas"*

Si es una tarea mensual, comparo la fecha de hoy con la de "ultima_realizacion"

*if(ultima_realizacion < hoy) echo "Tareas retrasadas"*

Con todo esto, lo que tengo que mostrar es:

- Si existe al menos una tarea retrasada, ya sea mensual o anual, que diga tareas retradas
- Si no hay tareas retrasadas, que muestre sin atraso.
- Si no está seteado el cliente, que muestre cliente si setear.

Hasta el momento, con ayuda de @sstan, pude llegar hasta acá:

```
SELECT
id_cliente,
coalesce(max(case when ultima_realizacion = '0000-00-00' then 1 end), 0) as tiene_0_ult_real,
coalesce(max(case when vencimiento = '0000-00-00' then 1 end), 0) as tiene_0_venc,
coalesce(max(case when ultima_realizacion = '0001-01-01' then 1 end), 0) as tiene_1_ult_real,
coalesce(max(case when vencimiento = '0001-01-01' then 1 end), 0) as tiene_1_venc,
min(case when ultima_realizacion not in ('0000-00-00', '0001-01-01') then ultima_realizacion end) as min_inicio,
min(case when vencimiento not in ('0000-00-00', '0001-01-01') then vencimiento end) as min_fin,
FROM tabla1
GROUP BY id_cliente
>ORDER BY id_cliente
```

junto con esto:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
if ($f['tiene_0_ult_real'] == 1 AND $f['tiene_0_venc'] == 1)
                {
                echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">"Cliente No Seteado"</td>';
                }
                else
                    {
                    if ($f['tiene_1_venc'] == 0 AND $f['tiene_0_ult_real'] == 1)
                        {
                        if ($diferencia >= 3 AND ($f['tiene_0_ult_real'] == 0 OR $f['tiene_0_venc'] == 0))
                            {
                            echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">"Tareas Retrasadas"</td>';                    
                            }
                        if ($diferencia <= 2 AND ($f['tiene_0_ult_real'] == 0 OR $f['tiene_0_venc'] == 0))
                            {
                            echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">"Sin Atraso"</td>';   
                            }
                        }

                    if ($f['tiene_1_venc'] == 1 AND $f['tiene_0_ult_real'] == 1)
                        {
                        if ($f['min_fin'] < $hoy)
                            {
                            echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">"Tareas Retrasadas"</td>';                    
                            }
                        if ($f['min_fin'] > $hoy)
                            {
                            echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">"Sin Atraso"</td>';   
                            }
                        if ($f['min_fin'] = $hoy)
                            {
                            echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">"Tarea Vence HOY!!!"</td>';   
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Espero que hayan podido entender. :D

Comment: En realidad no, está así porque la fórmula de atraso es un poco diferente, es decir, ultima_realizacion se compara contra la fecha de hoy 2 meses atrás. Porque se admite que haya un atraso de 2 meses. Por eso necesito diferenciar las mensuales de las anuales

Comment: No lo aclaré para nohacer más engorrosa la pregunta, pero el requerimiento es ese, tener las 2 fechas y poder jugar de esa manera con los 0000-00-00 y 0001-01-01

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración... Personalmente cuestionaría el requerimiento, solicitando que cambien la estructura de la tabla, pero entiendo que hay veces que no se puede cambiar.

Comment: Este es uno de los casos en que no se puede. En ciertas circunstnacias así como está anda, pero en otras falla :(

Comment: Acaba de ver tus otros mensajes. Si solucionastes tu problema, puedas agregarlo abajo como una respuesta (no en la pregunta misma). No hay nada malo en contestar tus propias preguntas. Aun le da oportunidad a otros para proponer mejor soluciones que te beneficien.

Comment: @sstan lo hice muy a lo bestia, pero por ahora salió bien en todas las pruebas que hice.

Comment: if (($f['tiene_0_ult_real'] == 1 AND $f['tiene_0_venc'] == 1) AND (($f['min_fin'] == '0000-00-00' AND $f['min_inicio'] == '0000-00-00') OR ($f['min_fin'] == '' AND $f['min_inicio'] == '')))
    {
    echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">"Cliente No Seteado"</td>';
    }
    else
     {

     if (($f['tiene_1_venc'] == 0 AND $f['tiene_1_ult_real'] == 1) OR ($f['tiene_0_venc'] == 1 AND $f['tiene_1_ult_real'] == 1))
      {

Comment: if ($diferencia >= 3 AND $f['min_inicio'] != '0001-01-01')
       {
       echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">Tareas Retrasadas o Vencidas!!!</td>';     
       }
       else
        {
        if ($f['min_fin'] != '0000-00-00' AND $f['min_fin'] != '0001-01-01' AND $diferencia >= 3 AND $f['min_fin'] < date("Y-m-d"))

Comment: {
         echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">Tareas Vencidassss</td>'; 
         }
        else
         {
         if ($diferencia <= 2 AND ($f['tiene_0_ult_real'] == 0 OR $f['tiene_0_venc'] == 0))
          {
          echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">Sin Atraso</td>'; 
          }
          else
           {
           if (($f['tiene_1_venc'] == 1 AND $f['tiene_0_ult_real'] == 1) OR

Comment: ($f['tiene_1_venc'] == 1 AND $f['tiene_1_ult_real'] == 0) AND $f['min_fin'] > '0001-01-01')
            {
            if ($f['min_fin'] < date("Y-m-d"))
             {
             echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">Tareas Retrasadas o Vencidas!</td>';     
             }
             else
              {
              if ($f['min_fin'] > date("Y-m-d"))
               {
               echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">Sin Atraso</td>'; 
               }
               else
                {

Comment: if ($f['min_fin'] = date("Y-m-d"))
                 {
                 echo '<td style="font-size:10px;">Tarea Vence HOY!</td>'; 
                 } 
                }
              }
            }
           }
         }
        }
      }
     }

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días, mi primera recomendación es que necesitas tres tareas, sí es posible y por la complejidad de cada tarea, deberías hacer tres procedimientos aparte.

Para la primera parte puedes hacer algo así:

```
SELECT tp.id_cliente, CASE 
   WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM Tabla1 t
      WHERE t.ultima_realizacion = '0000-00-00' 
      AND t.vencimiento = '0000-00-00' AND t.id_cliente = tp.id_cliente) 
   then 'NO SETEADO' 
   else 'SETEADO'
   end
FROM Tabla1 tp
GROUP BY tp.id_cliente
ORDER BY tp.id_cliente
```

Para el segundo caso:

```
SELECT 'Tarea Atrasada', tp.tarea, tp.id_cliente FROM Table1 tp
WHERE (tp.ultima_realizacion < GETDATE() AND tp.ultima_realizacion <> '0001-01-01') OR
(tp.vencimiento < GETDATE() AND tp.vencimiento  <> '0001-01-01')
GROUP BY tp.id_cliente, tp.tarea 
ORDER BY tp.id_cliente, tp.tarea
```

Para el tercer caso puedes hacer una modificación del caso dos, (asumo que lo quieres por usuario), agregando en la condición un `AND` y haciendo la comparación con el id de usuario deseado.

Por último, te recomiendo una reestructuración de dicha tabla, para que no tengas que guardar dos fechas. Algo rápido sería dejar la tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+------------+
| Id | vencimiento | tipo_tarea | tarea | id_cliente |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+------------+
```

Siendo de tipo bit el campo `tipo_tarea`. Ten en consideración lo siguiente:

- Sí es mensual la tarea, la fecha anual no se usa y viceversa.
- El calculo de sí una tarea está atrasada es el mismo para las tareas, sean mensuales o anuales.
- El revisar sí una tarea está seteada o no se vuelve más fácil.
- Es más eficiente revisar y comparar un bit, que dos fechas, para saber sí la tarea es anual o mensual.